# open chrome window every time it closes

Tags: services, web

How can I make it so that every time the chrome window is closed when it is open and closed, it will open again.
I have this code

@ECHO OFF

:inicio

taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe

cls

START chrome.exe --kiosk -priting https://www.google.com.mx/?hl=es

timeout 300 > NUL

cls

goto inicio

Comment: Whats wrong with kiosk mode?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: that closes the browser window and we make it reopen automatically